# What is the time complexity of this for loop?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

```
for(i=0; i < n; i * = 25)
```

As far as I think the complexity cannot be determined.
The iteration never proceeds, so that the loop basically turns up to be infinite loop.

Comment: It depends on the value of `n`, it is not true that it never proceeds.

Comment: It's constant time if n <= 0, and infinite if n > 0.

Comment: Or something else entirely, if `i` is modified in the body of the loop!

Comment: 25 * 0  = 0, so your `$i` starts as 0 and will ALWAYS be 0. Therefore this loop has complexity O(infinity).

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comments, the loop only terminates for `n ≤ 0`. For every other `n`, the program does not terminate.

I think you don't want to talk about complexities if you have something that never terminates, as complexities are used to get an idea of running times for big inputs and to compare algorithms.

You cannot even say the code you have is an algorithm, since the definition of an algorithm often contains, that it has to terminate.

If you are required to write down something in big-o there are more than one way to look at this.

1. The algorithm never terminates, so it makes infinite operations and you cannot find a constant number `c` and a function `f(n)` (polynomial or exponential) with `∞ < c⋅f(n)` for `n < ∞`, so it should be `O(∞)`.
   This is supported by the formal definition of big-o.
2. If you look at change of the number of executed operation, if you double the input, `n → 2n` you see, that the number of executed operations does not change, so maybe `O(1)` is also possible.
   This is supported by the recurrence formula `T(n) = T(n-1)`. At the end you have to define what `T(1)` is. Complexity has nothing to do with small or specific inputs, so maybe one could define `T(1) = O(1)`.

Both ways say, that the running time does not depend on the input, but the second one is mostly philosophic and the first one should be the preferred one.

But as I said at the beginning: You don't want to talk about complexities on code that never terminates (or only for irrelevant cases).